# MongoDB Applying multiply over divide giving error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am doing a query on mongodb in which i am first finding the set intersection and dividing it by some constant and now i want to multiply the value with some constant.Here is my code snippet for that

```
"score":
       {
         "$divide":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":['$token_list',tokens]}},tokens_size]
                                               
       }
```

It is workign fine ad giving correct result now when i am applying $multiply over it.It is giving syntax error

```
"score":
        {
         "$multiply":["$divide":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":['$token_list',tokens]}},tokens_size],10]
                                               
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put divide result into another object:

```
"score":
    {
     "$multiply":[
         {
            "$divide":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":['$token_list',tokens]}},tokens_size]
         }, 10]
                                           
    }
```